# Is it the best way to use Angular 8 and JSP for developing Social Network web application

Tags: java, angular, spring, web

I am developing a social network web application. I already built the login and registration pages with all validation using Angular 8 as front end and Java, Spring framework as back end. Next step when a user login I want user goes to his profile where can add his photo, upload photos, and can look to others profile and comment and like to others photos. have a few questions:

1. Is it the best way to use JSP or not?
2. What technologies I should use when I want to redirect from one page to another page? For example I want a user be able to go to others profile and like and comment?

Comment: Hello, JSP is there to render HTML by the backend, but you already have Angular for HTML rendering in the frontend. These are two different approaches. If you want to stay with Angular, you could use Spring Rest Controller to send data from the backend to the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stay with Angular, I don't see reason to mix JSP with Angular, especially if you have that one already. Otherwise you lose rendering time advantage in Angular.
Here is great example https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-2-angular-7-example
how to create nice clean Angular/Spring Boot application.